# How to configure Fluent NHibernate to return null instead of proxies for missing objects when using ReferencesAny

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

As per the title, I have an object which has a ReferencesAny association, but it's possible that the referenced object may have been deleted. If this has occurred, currently the missing object is initialized with a proxy which then throws ObjectNotFound if accessed. I want to be able to have this return null instead, in a similar fashion to setting not-found to "ignore" on other properties. I understand the differences between using Session.Get and Session.Load but this is occurring as a result of a LINQ query.

So, my question is, how can I specify that null should be returned for missing objects for an "any" association?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using **xml** configuration, but I guess that my hint could help you anyway... NHibernate provides for those *incomplete* mappings an attribute **not-found** which is by default set to "**exception**". In this example is reference *many-to-one* mapping, but it could be used even for *one-to-many*

```
<many-to-one name="MyReferencedObject" not-found="exception" />
```

but it can be changed to **ignore**

```
<many-to-one name="MyReferencedObject" not-found="ignore" />
```

In that case the result will be NULL. (But be careful, NHibernate will always execute a SQL select statement, because such a "NULL" value won't be cached)

**EDIT**: based on the comment below, I have to say, that my suggestion is not working for **<any>** mapping. Sorry for that, I should read more carefully...
But, please, let me provide you with suggestion, how to fix it.

We can introduce event listener. More can be found here http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-events

*Solution in a nutshell:*

**Introduce the event listener**

```
public class PostLoadListener 
           : NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultPostLoadEventListener
{ ... }
```

and inject it into the "session-factory" configuration.

```
<event type="post-load">
    <listener class="MyLib.PostLoadListener, MyLib"/>
</event>
```

The trick would be inside of the overriden method *OnPostLoad*

```
public override void OnPostLoad(PostLoadEvent @event)
{
    base.OnPostLoad(@event);

    // the entity with <any> mapping 
    ConvertToNull(@event.Entity as MyAuditEntity); 
}

protected virtual void ConvertToNull(MyAuditEntity item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        // access some property to check that reference is not a PROXY
        var id = item.AnyEntity.ID;
    }
    catch
    {
        // replace proxy with null
        item.AnyEntity = null; 
    }
}
```

Of course, this is not the answer like not-found="ignore". But this workaround will do that job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Radim, but I'm specifically looking at an ANY association. I don't believe that the not-found attribute is valid on that element, is it?

Comment: Honestly, I've incorrectly read the "ReferencesAny" in your question. You are right in <any> mapping this is not available.